# Kotlin List Objects to List Id's

Tags: list, kotlin, object, foreach, entity

I have a list of objects Human. I need to get a list of its id. I do that. Can i do it more simplier? It looks not so good

```
  val idsList = ArrayList<Int>()
humansList.forEach{idsList.add(it.id)}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can simply [map](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html) ids from `humanList` to `idsList`

```
val idsList = humalList.map { it.id }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to kotlin so I don't understand why accepted answer didn't work for me

I used the below code:

```
val idsList = (0..humalList.size-1).toList()
```